# How many even numbers are there in a set $\{x_1, x_2 ... x_n\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

For example how to calculate how many even numbers are in a set $\{45, 46, 47 ... 456\}$. General question is how to calculate how many even numbers are in a given set of natural numbers which doesn't starts from $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us consider a set $\{a,a+1,\cdots,b-1,b\}$ where $1\lt a\lt b\in\mathbb N$.

Case 1 : If $a,b$ are even, the answer is $1+(b-a)/2$.

Case 2 : If $a,b$ are odd, the answer is $(b-a)/2$.

Case 3 : If $a$ is even and $b$ is odd, then the answer is $1+(b-a-1)/2.$

Case 4 : If $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then the answer is the same as case 3.

Yours is case 4, so the answer is $1+(456-45-1)/2$.

**P.S.** You can use these formulas in the case of $a=1$.

Comment: @oldrinb : Thanks. I didn't notice it:)

Comment: Could I generalize these formulas if I'm looking for how many numbers in a set are divisible by any natural number n?

Comment: Yes, but we have to separate cases as above. So, you can, but it is not so easy and fun, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Since you suggest that you know how to calculate how many even numbers are in a set that *does* start with 1, why not calculate how many even numbers are in $\{1, 2, \ldots, 456\}$, then how many even numbers are in $\{1, 2, \ldots, 44\}$, and then subtract?

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary set of natural numbers, there is no shorter way to count the number of even numbers other than considering each number individually.

I will assume that you are considering a set of natural numbers forming an arithmetic progression. The sequence starts with $a_1$ and $a_{k+1} = a_{k} + d$. There are $n$ terms in total. Note: $n = \frac{b-a}{d} + 1$, where $b$ is the last term and $a$ is the first.

If $d$ is even and $a_1$ is odd, there are no even numbers.

If $d$ is even and $a_1$ is even, all $n$ terms are even.

If $d$ is odd and $a_1$ is odd, then the $k$th term is even iff $k$ is even. So the answer is $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, using the notation of the floor function.

If $d$ is odd and $a_1$ is even, then the $k$th term is even iff $k$ is odd. So the answer is $\lceil n/2 \rceil$, using the ceiling function. Note that $\lceil n \rceil$ is $n$ for integers, not $n+1$.